# Linux UART driver - debugging time taken for __init call

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

I am a bit new to the Linux kernel and our team is trying to optimize the boot-up time for the device. It was observed that 8250 UART driver takes more than 1 second to complete the __init call. Using printk's and going by the generated console time-stamps prefixed to every log message, I was able to narrow down the function call which takes the extra time:

ret = platform_driver_register(&serial8250_isa_driver);

Being a novice, I was unsure about what more could I do from a debugging standpoint to track down the issue ? I am looking for pointers/suggestions from some of the experienced Kernel developers out there.. Just curious as to what other approach would the Kernel developers, use from their "Debugging Toolbox" ?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, the register function is doing stuff with that struct (maybe polling addresses or something). You would need to see if any of the functions defined within are being called by register.

To more answer your question, does the platform you're running on have an 8250 ISA UART? If not, that could well explain why it's taking so long to init (it's timing out).

Comment: The 8250 was the canonical UART in its day. What we'll most likely be seeing here is a 8250 register-compatible device integrated into a larger device.   This is very common.